# How to parse the output of Applescript which is in object format to text?

Tags: applescript

currently am running to retrieve entire contents of window from Applescript in Java, applescript is returning class objects which is not happening if i run the same script from java, pls suggest how to format the same.

```
tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Install Adobe Flash Player"

      set tElements to entire contents of window 1

        end tell
end tell
tElements
```

output :

```
{button 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", button 2 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", button 3 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", image 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", group 2 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", static text "Adobe Flash Player 11" of group 2 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", progress indicator 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", group 3 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", static text "  " of group 3 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", image 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", group 4 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", static text "Error: General installation error" of group 4 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", button "Finish" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events", static text "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer" of application process "Install Adobe Flash Player" of application "System Events"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to target one of them... which one? You don't say. However normally you get the "value" of one of those objects. So for example you would do something like this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Install Adobe Flash Player"
       set theValue to value of group 2 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer"
    end tell
end tell
```

And if the "value" doesn't work then you can get the properties of the object and see which property you want...

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Install Adobe Flash Player"
           set theProperties to properties of group 2 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Adobe Flash Player Installer"
        end tell
end tell
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I dont want to hardcode here like group 2, UI element etc. so thats the reason I went with parsing the output of entire contents of window in Java..